# v-model vs props for custom Vue components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Is v-model in Vue is a built-in feature that works only for few selected tags? Does props feature is an alternative to v-model?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect my core question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is v-model in Vue is a built-in feature that works only for few selected tags?

`v-model` is a [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) that works on form elements by default, but you can use it in your own components as well. It's really just shorthand for a component that accepts a property named "value" and emits an event named "input".

Here's boilerplate for an arbitrary component that uses v-model:

```
<template>
  <div>
    My value is {{displayValue}}
    <button @click="go">Change it</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'exampleComponent',
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {displayValue: ''}
  },
  mounted() {
    this.displayValue = this.value; // initialize internal variables
  },
  watch: {
    value() {
      // Parent property changed; update internal variables
      this.displayValue = this.value;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    go() {
      // example change handler
      this.$emit('input', "NEW VALUE"); // tell the parent to update to the new value. This will update via the watch:value()
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

A parent component could then just do `<example-component v-model="someVariable"></example-component>`, as with any other form element.

> props feature is an alternative to v-model?

Only for half of it.  Props are a way to pass a value down to a child component, but on their own they don't give you a way to communicate changes in that value back up to the parent component; for that you need to `$emit` the changed value.

(You can also do this perfectly well without `v-model`, of course, using your own named props and emits, but I find that if I stick to the `v-model` structure, I don't have to think as much; when I come back six months later to change something it's a lot easier to understand what I was doing.)

Answer (score 1):

Your questions:

> Is v-model in Vue is a built-in feature that works only for few
> selected tags?

Yes, `v-model` works for all tags that user can interact or modify the data: `input, textarea, radio, select`...

You could use `v-model` for custom HTML’s built-in input types. Vue components allow you to build reusable inputs with completely customized behavior. See more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events)

> Does props feature is an alternative to v-model?

No, `props` is the way that a parent component share data with it's children, and `v-model` is a data binding (two-way data bindings) in the same component, form or user input...

I recommend you to read the [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)...